# Anchor link with Revolution Slider

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

Anyone using Revolution Slider can help me?

I added a link the image below

[rev-slide screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQQJd.png)


When I click on this layer, I get the correct link "https://domain/#investigation" but the page don't scroll till the right section.

But if I open in a different window the same "https://domain/#investigation", the link works as expected!

There's something I can do?

Comment: @KrupalPanchal I have this page https://www.evaapplications.com/investigation-tool-2/. I want the pink part of the circle to link to https://www.evaapplications.com/investigation-tool-2/#investigation. The link is set in the circle with rev. slider as the image above. if you go directly to https://www.evaapplications.com/investigation-tool-2/#investigation, the page scroll to the right section. But when I click in the slider, nothing happens  :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys!

I was able to find a solution linking to the row's ID and not to the anchor link.